# Split em ordem inversa

Tags: javascript, json

```
var itens: "101|102|103|104";

var quebra = itens.split("|");
    for (var i = quebra.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    var unidade = quebra[i];

$("#lista").append("<p>" +getValue(unidade, jsonTitles)+"</p>");
}
```

o resultado disso é o seguinte:
104
103
102
101

precisaria que fosse 
101
102
103
104

Answer (score 4):

Basta usar o método **reverse**.

```js
var itens = "101|102|103|104";

var quebra = itens.split("|").reverse(); // inverte o array
for (var i = quebra.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  var unidade = quebra[i];
  console.log(unidade);
}
```

Comment: as duas funcionaram... obrigado laerte

Comment: Disponha, o objeto array possui vários métodos interessantes. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Adicione `.sort(function (a, b) { return b - a; })` logo depois do `itens.split("|")`.

Comment: funcionou perfeitamente.. alias essa forma da mais opções da saida. obrigado

Comment: Valeu! Sempre quando você precisar estaremos aqui.